# UIPDFPageRenderOperation object 0x12de5fcf0 overreleased while already deallocating; break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I'm adding some PDF links to my UIWebView and every time one loads and I make a scroll gesture, I get this error: “UIPDFPageRenderOperation object 0x14acaca10 overreleased while already deallocating; break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug”.
So, is the UIPDF is being deallocated while I try to scroll?

Anyone have a hint?

If I scroll really fast then I even get a crash. Still happens on iOs 9.3.3.

```
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 20)];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/userName/Desktop/bigIcd.pdf"];

[webView loadFileURL:url allowingReadAccessToURL:url];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: maybe you should enhance your question by adding some source code about how you're using the UIPDF...

Comment: @ddb I don't think the asker is directly using a `UIPDFPageRenderOperation`. Instead `UIWebView` and `WKWebView` use that "behind the scenes" when loading a PDF. I'm having a similar issue, except I'm just seeing this error printed and no crashes _yet_.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue... It does not crash, however, log shows this... and loads normally after a while... Is this a bug that we should file to Apple?

Comment: I don't know, I found some well-known applications also have this problem, such as WeChat  , QQ .